# Listing Files with PHP and start a new Row

Tags: php, html, list, file

I would like list files from a folder and put them into a list.
The list should split each 3 files. The list will be cards from Materialize,
so thats why I would like to start a new row each 3 files.
How would I achieve something like this?
Could someone help me?
Thanks :)

Comment: Hello, can you show the code you have tried ?

Comment: `if ($counter == 3) { echo 'somethig'; }`

Answer (score 0):

```
        <?php 
            $myDirectory = opendir("./downloads");
            while($entryName = readdir($myDirectory)) {
                $dirArray[] = $entryName;
            }
            closedir($myDirectory);
            //  count elements in array
            $indexCount = count($dirArray);
            // sort 'em
            sort($dirArray);

            // loop through the array of files and print them all
            for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
                if (substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1) != "."){ // don't list hidden files


                    print('<li class="collection-item dismissable"><div>'.$dirArray[$index].'<a href="https://DOMAIN.xyz/downloads/'.$dirArray[$index].'" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">send</i></a></div></li>');
                }
            }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) with PHP5.6+
That'll look the following

```
$dir = "somepath";
$files = Array(Array(), Array(), Array()); // This should set up 3 nested arrays
$ind = 0;

foreach(new DirectoryIterator($dir) as $fileInfo) {
  if ($fileInfo->isDot()) continue;
  if ($ind >= 3) $ind = 0;
  array_push($files[$ind], $fileInfo->getFileName());
  $ind++;
}
```